# MySQL - Duplicate Entry when trying to install a Plugin

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, plugins

I'm trying to install a Plugin on my MySQL database, but each time I try I get a Duplicate Entry error:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN audit_log SONAME 'audit_log.so';
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'audit_log' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

But If I run:

```
SHOW PLUGINS;
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`plugins`;
```

There is no sign of it.

If I run `SELECT * FROM mysql.plugin;` then there is an entry for it.

But If I run `UNINSTALL PLUGIN audit_log;` then it tells me it doesn't exist. `Error Code: 1305. PLUGIN audit_log does not exist`

I know the file is there, because there are two databases on this server running under `mysqld_multi` and it installed fine under the other one.

The server is 5.5.54, the server is Debian 8 (jessie).

Is there anything else I can do? Can I simply delete it from the `mysql.plugin` table without causing problems? Restarting the server isn't feasible as it is my master database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I renamed the entry in `mysql.plugin`, and then I was able to install it. Once I checked it was OK I then removed the entry in `mysql.plugin`.

So far it seems to be working fine,

Comment: FWIW I ran into the same issue today (could have been caused by an unattended MariaDB upgrade); I did a `DELETE FROM mysql.plugin WHERE name = "CONNECT"` and I was on my merry way. Thanks!